# Boot picking up property file from dependency instead of application

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I am using spring boot and I have added another spring boot app as Maven dependency in my project. The problem I am facing is that when I run the application, it picks the property file of the dependency instead of my current application. For example if I run the app using dev profile, application-dev.property file is picked from dependency instead of the running application.
I tried to debug the *EnableEncryptablePropertySourcesPostProcessor* file and below is the screenshot of the list of property file picked.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this out](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files) but you have a few options:

1. Simply specify the config file name:

   java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.name=myproject

And basically you can have myproject-dev.properties

2. Or directly specify the config files you wanna import:

   java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.location=classpath:/default.properties,classpath:/override.properties

Comment: I added `System.setProperty("spring.config.name","application-newName");` in the main method of the SpringBootApplication class and renamed the property files and it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

Use **PropertySource** annotation to refer the properties file in your main application file as shown below

```
@PropertySource(value = { "file:/path/to/folder/file.properties" })
```

If you have same property in the multiple properties file then one in the classpath will get more preference

Comment: This page may be of use since I'm not sure that last statement is completely accurate. It contains the order in which properties are resolved. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Answer (score 0):

**In Application.java file it should be something like this

@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")